# How can I set Compose Key under KDE5/Plasma to <Right Shift>+<Ctrl>

Tags: keyboard-layout, settings, kde5

I reinstalled my system and now use KDE5 instead of KDE4. The system (e.g. in boot) uses the Compose Key I'm used to - Press <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>e</kbd> and I get æ.

But I'm unable to convince KDE to do so. In the KDE Keyboard expert settings I achived that it is now <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>.

Question: How can I setup to either use system settings or set <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> as I'm used to?

Comment: are you running under wayland or x11?  (`env | grep XDG_SESSION_TYPE`)  .. if x11, what's the output of `setxkbmap -query`?

Comment: loginctl says it's an x11 session althought I don't see any Xorg process anymore. Output is (rules: evdev / model: pc101 / layout: de / variant: nodeadkeys / options: compose:rctrl,compose:shift+rctrl,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,compose:rctrl-altgr) but only the last compose works (and the second is what I want).

Comment: Clearing options (setxkbmap -option) and (setxkbmap -option compose:shift+rctrl) does not work, but clearing and (setxkbmap -option compose:rctrl-altgr) restores behaviour, so default KDE5 is stealing shift+rctrl somewhere?